# Multiple Azure Subscriptions Using a Single Domain Controller

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine, domaincontroller, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to use an Azure virtual machine that's setup as a domain controller to manage virtual machines hosted on other Azure subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have never tried this before, but do not immediately see an issue with it.

I assume your Domain Controller is deployed using Microsoft's guidelines including assigning a static IP address?

With the ability to connect one VNet to another VNet (See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/) you can create the required network connectivity.

What you probably need to do is use your own DNS server for name resolution (See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/) in all connected VNets. I would recommend running DNS on your Domain Controller.

One thing to consider however is the generated traffic for authentication and name resolution. Do know that Azure is charging for traffic traversing from one Azure region to another.

Hope this helps you moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario  is it required to create DNS server per subscription or one DNS server is enough for multiple subscription.